# Why can't I ping a PC on my home network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, tcpip, ping

Whenever I try to ping another box on my home network, it pings the wrong ip address:

```
C:\Users\Papa>ping macmini
Pinging macmini.belkin [208.68.143.55] with 32 bytes of data: 
Reply from 208.68.143.55: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=110
```

As you can see it always appends belkin to anything I try to ping.  So I hit up `ipconfig` and `belkin` happens to be Connection-specific DNS Suffix:

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : belkin
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.7
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

My setup is all DHCP, so I am not sure where `belkin` is coming from.  I looked through all the networking stuff, as you can see below:
[image]

Bottom line: how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That IP resolves to `dnssearch.rr.com`. Looks like a misconfiguration in that you are actually pinging a DNS search rather than using it...

The misconfiguration is more than likely present at your router than at your computer. Try changing the DNS servers the router is using to Google DNS at `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  It had `belkin` as the domain in the router config page.  Which is really odd, as it's a linksys router.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure you ping to correct host, you may use

```
ping <ip-address>
```

If you ping by using name (eg: macmini), it will refer to DNS service specified on your network.  The DNS service will serve the request and return the IP address associated to the name you try to ping.  If the DNS service doesn't return the expected IP-address, you may have to check the configuration of DNS service.  This is another big topic.

Comment: that's exactly the issue, it appends `belkin`.  That is what I want to fix (big topic or not).

Comment: You need to go into your router's configuration and remove the DNS suffix. Sometimes this is simply called "Domain Name" too, but I would consult your router's documentation.

Comment: @vcsjones  You are right on the money.  That resolved the issue.